# Getting error while trying to install svgtools

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to install [PocketVJ](https://github.com/magdesign/PocketVJ-CP-v3/) using [these instructions.](https://gist.github.com/baydam/a905e4878f54150f7da421e2c1d17a21/)
The problem I'm facing is svgtools, when trying to install it via `sudo pip install svgtools` , am I only getting a few error messages.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install svgtools
Requirement already satisfied: pjlink in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-osc in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.6.8)
Collecting svgtools
Collecting svgpathtools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/96/cc91050f3b53c2cea0eda18f371d0584e7f43713ce606738384e8001a877/svgpathtools-1.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting svgwrite
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/27/a29fc710b5fc4dc8031d55e903c1352a194df4014dccf8b507049dd754e6/svgwrite-1.1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pjlink) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pjlink) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from svgtools) (0.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from svgtools) (2.2.2)
Collecting scipy (from svgtools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/76/7e844757b9f3bf5ab9f951ccd3e4a8eed91ab8720b0aac8c2adcc2fdae9f/scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from svgtools) (1.14.5)
Collecting scikit-image (from svgtools)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from svgtools) (0.28.4)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from svgtools) (2.1)
Collecting scikit-learn (from svgtools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/b6/454cf208be93efa3db50ce06b732328c57ede005d1dcfa71d9a1548530b0/scikit-learn-0.19.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from svgwrite) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas->svgtools) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas->svgtools) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->svgtools) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->svgtools) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools-lru-cache in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->svgtools) (1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: subprocess32 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->svgtools) (3.5.2)
Collecting cloudpickle>=0.2.1 (from scikit-image->svgtools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/bf/60ae7ec1e8c6742d2abbb6819c39a48ee796793bcdb7e1d5e41a3e379ddd/cloudpickle-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dask[array]>=0.9.0 (from scikit-image->svgtools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/77/a22c04d952cdf2613d258d00a3d7560752cd4c8a16eee1d2c84ab45a220d/dask-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyWavelets>=0.4.0 (from scikit-image->svgtools)
Collecting pillow>=4.3.0 (from scikit-image->svgtools)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from networkx->svgtools) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->svgtools) (5.5.1)
Collecting toolz>=0.7.3; extra == "array" (from dask[array]>=0.9.0->scikit-image->svgtools)
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy, scikit-learn
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-LnnsUw --python-tag cp27:
  /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Running from scipy source directory.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py", line 388, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1024, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 993, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 930, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1024, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 993, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 930, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

  ----------------------------------------
  ***Failed building wheel for scipy***
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


  ----------------------------------------
  **Failed cleaning build dir for scipy**
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-DVda1j --python-tag cp27:
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 148, in get_scipy_status
      import scipy
  ImportError: No module named scipy
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 269, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 259, in setup_package
      .format(scipy_req_str, instructions))
  ImportError: Scientific Python (SciPy) is not installed.
  scikit-learn requires SciPy >= 0.13.3.
  Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html


  ----------------------------------------
  **Failed building wheel for scikit-learn**
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scipy scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: scipy, cloudpickle, toolz, dask, PyWavelets, pillow, scikit-image, scikit-learn, svgtools, svgwrite, svgpathtools
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-6oZv6e/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/atlas-base
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py", line 474, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py", line 388, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1024, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 993, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 930, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1024, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 993, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 930, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 19, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-6oZv6e/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-UXPxBQ/scipy/
```

I hope that someone will be able to help me with my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why the system would complain about more than 8 links if you include the log file directly; did you use code block formatting for the logs (select all and Ctrl+K)? Maybe it's interpreting part of your logs as a link when it shouldn't do?

Comment: Thank you, fixed it. Now the logs are in the question and not on an external site.

Comment: If you try running `sudo apt-get install python-sklearn` then rerun Pip, does that have any effect? It looks like Pip might be having problems with installing scipy etc.